# How do I know last package version for an old Fedora version

Tags: linux, google-chrome, installation, fedora

I have an old version of Fedora, version 18, and I need to install google-chrome as well as other packages. However when installing google-chrome, version 43, I'm getting errors for a number of dependencies I should have. I think it is due to having an old Fedora version, version 18. I can not update it because Fedora 22 is too slow in my old PC.

```
[rodolk@Gandalf Downloads]$ sudo yum install google-chrome-stable
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package google-chrome-stable.x86_64 0:43.0.2357.132-1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: lsb >= 4.0 for package: google-chrome-stable-43.0.2357.132-1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libnss3.so(NSS_3.14.3)(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-43.0.2357.132-1.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-43.0.2357.132-1.x86_64 (google-chrome)
           Requires: lsb >= 4.0
Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-43.0.2357.132-1.x86_64 (google-chrome)
           Requires: libnss3.so(NSS_3.14.3)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
[rodolk@Gandalf Downloads]$
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution could be to tweak your `/etc/yum.repos.d/fedora.repo` file to force him to point on the fedora 18 old repo. Unfortunately I don't think they are maintained anymore (see the void directory at http://mirror.chpc.utah.edu/pub/fedora/linux/releases/).

Otherwise, you can try older versions of chrome (available at http://www.filehippo.com/download_google_chrome/) but you'll have to refuse any proposed upgrade if you manage to install it. Not a good solution tho, because of possible security breach present in older versions.

I suggest installing Fedora with a lightweight GUI (which I suspect is the reason of the degraded peformances on your old machine), like KDE or xfce. You can find more choices here: https://spins.fedoraproject.org/.

Comment: Thanks. I'm pointing to http://archive.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/18/Fedora/x86_64/ and it's working